# Linux script to print users with largest num of files

Tags: bash, unix, operating-system

I am trying to write a script which for each directory given on standard input (in a separate line) prints the user with the largest number of files in this directory.

Example:

```
$ thewinneris << STOP
> /etc
> /tmp
> /home/users/jakubo
> STOP
root
killertrashman
jakubo
```

this is what I got so far:

```
while IFS= read -r dirname; do ..//stuck-here//. ;done
```

not quite sure what to do next tho, would love some guidance. Thanks!

Comment: Shall files in subdirectories also be counted?

Comment: @Armali Yes subdirectories should also be counted :)

Answer (score 0):

In place of the `..//stuck-here//.` you could determine the file owners with `find`, the file count for each user with `sort|uniq` and the highest count's user with `sort -n|awk`:

```
find "$dirname" -printf %u\\n|sort|uniq -c|sort -n|awk 'END {print $2}'
```